# Excel - Hide rows that have no values in a column set

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

So I have a requirement that works as follows.

Given a column set `C_1,C_2,....C_N`

and a subset of those columns

`C_n....C_N`

that contain non-basic information.

Hide any rows that have no values in

`C_n...C_N` where `n>1`.

This has the added complication of when column `C_i`, where `n < i < N`, is hidden it no longer counts as having a value when deciding whether or not to hide a row.

I don't know whether such a thing is possible with excel (though maybe with macros/vb code?).

Any suggestions

Comment: I don't know if this helps but you could transpose the enire spreedsheet. Afterwards you can use autofilter on the rows (former columns) and now you are able to slect non empty columns. All empty are filtered out

Comment: Hi, I have a partial solution but hesitate to add as a answer as some might see this as incorrect method to show code. I am welling to share if that is not an issue. In short the code iterates UsedRows and UsedColumns. This means if row 1 has three cells and row 5 has 10 cells each row is check against all 10 cells so this may or may not work for you.

Comment: Hi, Schafwolle I'm playing around with the transpose idea but am having some issues with the hidden column aspect, and since I'm much better with code than excel, linking the columns back to the rows. Karen Payne, would your method essentially evaluate the value of every cell in the `C_n...C_N` range? Or the entire sheet?

Comment: I'm also attempting to try and count the number of not hidden cells in a range that have a value. This is going poorly.